# How can I set multiple types of return values?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell can return multiple values without array or hash table like this;

```
function FooBar1() {
  return "foobar", 1
}
$foo, $bar = FooBar1
$foo # "foobar"
$bar # 1
```

But when defining types of return values this kind of syntax is invalid, so what is the correct syntax?

```
# INCORRECT SYNTAX
class Foo {
  static [String, Int]Bar() {
    return "foobar", 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type you're returning ends up being `[System.Object[]]`. You still aren't technically returning multiple types, just an array of objects.

```
function FooBar1() {
  return "foobar", 1
}

gm -i (FooBar1)
```

The reason the assignment works the way it does is that that method works with any array:

```
$a = 1,2,3

$one, $two, $three = $a
```

So this should work:

```
class Foo {
  static [Object[]]Bar() {
    return "foobar", 1
  }
}
```

If you know that you'll be returning objects of the same type, it's probably preferable to indicate that:

```
class Foo {
  static [String[]]Bar() {
    return "foo", "bar"
  }
}
```